# Escape sequence in C++ enclosed in single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: c++, c

I've been using C and C++ since quite a while, and I just happened to come across a program that had single quotes for \n like it was a character ( '\n' ) . It serves the purpose alright, and my assumption is something on the lines of a string consisting of an array of characters and \n is a single character and hence doesn't make any difference. My 2 questions are:

1. Why isn't this methodology popular?
2. Is \n actually a single character as I'm assuming it to be?

Comment: @ChrisCulter, not really. OP knows chars and string, but apparently not escape sequences. (The question probably is a duplicate, though, just not for the question that you linked.)

Comment: @Yu Hao No,  I was referring to us mostly using "\n " and not  '\n'.

Comment: The difference between `"\n"` and `'\n'` is the same as the difference between `"a"` and `'a'`. You use the one you need, a string literal or a single `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["Escape sequences"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). `'\n'` ubiquitously means newline. In ASCII this is code 10 (0x0A). All C derived languages (C++, Java, JavaScript, but also e.g. Prolog, Bash, Python, …) use `'\n'` as escape sequence for the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

They are single characters, called [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). We need to be able to see and type them so they are written as a combination of visible characters available on keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference between "\n" and '\n' is that "\n" is a string with a newline character (i.e. a buffer consisting on two bytes: 0x0A and 0x00, being 0x00 the standard end of line indicator in C strings) whereas '\n' is just the constant 0x0A.

Comment: "whereas '\n' is just the constant 0x0A": this part is not entirely correct. C does not mandate the encoding. E.g. in EBCDIC the code for a newline is different.